# Handling Ajax After Session Timeout

Tags: php, ajax, session-timeout

When the session timeouts, the pages that are requested by the browser redirect to the login page. I also have some pages that return json to ajax requests. Now when the session timeouts, these pages can return something like `{sessiontimeout:1}` instead of what they're supposed to return. However, this means I have to put the check in all of my ajax response functions. Or i could wrap the ajax function to handle that:

```
success:function(result){
  if(result.sessiontimeout){
    window.location.href = login page;
  }else{realfunction(result)}
}
```

My question is, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: That way looks fine. What more could you want?

Answer (score 0):

There's another way to do it is using a jQuery PHP library and I use it a lot, you can find it here http://code.google.com/p/jquery-php/downloads/list  and how to use it http://jquery.hohli.com/.

Here's how it gonna work. to check if the session is closed then you redirect the user using a jQuery plugin like this one add the following in you script file.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.jRedirect = function(location, time) {  
         return this.each(function() { 
            window.setTimeout ( function() {
           window.location = location; 
        },time*1000);
         });  
     } 
})(jQuery)
```

make sure you add this on your page:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="YOUR_PATH.jquery.php.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="YOUR_PATH.jquery.form.js" ></script>
```

and then add a button like this one:

```
<a onclick="$.php('ajax.php');"> Check user</a>
```

on the ajax.php file you put this:

```
include(YOUR_PATH_TO.'jQuery.php'); // from the download

//Note: make sure you already declared session start and see if there's a session.

if($session_out){ // check if session is out then redirect 

jQuery('body')->jRedirect('login page');

}else{

jQuery('#message')->html('I'm already logged in');
```

}

```
jQuery::getResponse();
```

I hope you get it right, it's alternative solution and it works 100%.

Answer (score 0):

**As you know that what will be "the server response for the ajax request" then go for check with any basic values is returned or not i.g. if json object contain the "id" key then check "id" is exist or not. If yes means your data there else redirect user or refresh that page. Or show proper message**